# custom numbered lists with css

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to control the text used for the numbering?

For example, is there a way to have the list automatically do something like this:

```
First,     blah-blah
Second,    blah-blah
Third,     blah-blah
Fourth,    blah-blah
etc.
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make it clearer. At present the question doesn't seem to be anything like what you are asking for in the comments to the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yR6G6/

What we are doing here is adding a pseudo :before element to each LI and customizing its content with JavaScript.

**NOTE**: This solution assumes you are ok using JS and jQuery. A pure CSS solution is likely not possible at all.

---

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    color: red;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JS**

```
var labels = [
    "First",
    "Second",
    "Third"
    // and so on...    
];

$('ul li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-label', labels[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to only indent the second line. You could do something like this:

```
li {
    text-indent: -1em;
    padding-left: 1em;  
}
```

You'll need to play around with those values, and with the values for the `<ul>` or `<ol>` element to get everything right.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp

This really doesn't look like the appropriate answer without reading your comment about indentation...